# Should I use .htaccess file for my VPS or only httpd.conf

Tags: .htaccess

I started to optimize my wordpress blog and one of what I need  to  do is to configure .htaccess file. I have a VPS -> CentOS, so I need to move all my rules from .htaccess to httpd.conf? Also, I use W3C Total Cache for Wordpress, and this plugin inserted some rules in my .htacces file, what I should do with this code?
Thanks and sorry please my Enghlish

Comment: I'm not sure how big the performance gain is. My guess is that it is minor, compared to the network time. I would suggest first doing things that will really help, like setting up compression, and adding expires headers for static content. Using sprites instead of a lot of small images. Basically all the thing Yahoo's YSlow, and Google's PageSpeed suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Apache best practice is to use your system or vhost config -- if necessary with `<Directory>` filters -- and to disable `.htaccess` files if you have (root) access to you system config.  The upside here is that there are less pitfalls in using the root config and there is also a performance bonus.   The downside is that you will need to restart Apache when you change the configuration.

People (and the Apache docs) often discuss performance hit of using .htaccess files, but in terms of CPU load this is minimal (~1 mSec per file parsed).  *However*, the main benefit is in I/O savings because if you do have .htaccess files enabled then Apache searches the entire path to any requested file for putative `.htaccess` files.  OK, these will all end up in the VFS cache on a dedicated system, but these probes still involve a lot of cache I/O with can add up to ~10 mSec per request even if fully cached.

One other thing to be aware of is the root, vhost and directory rules are by nature single pass whereas the `.htaccess`processing is a while loop which keeps selecting and retrying the deepest `.htaccess` file until no more rewrite changes are made.  And there are subtle syntax differences in regexps and substitute rules.

Independent of all this is the point that Gerben makes about network tuning which I endorse 100% wherever you address these issues.